# Locked out of postgresql

Tags: macos, postgresql

`createdb foo` gives an invalid password for user (my username)

I can't login with

`sudo psql`

How do I reset my postgres user accounts?

Is it something I can do in the hba_conf file?

EDIT:

I was beginning a Postgres tutorial and wanted to have a fresh install. I ran

```
brew update
brew uninstall postgresql
brew install postgresql
pg_ctl -D some/path
createdb
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you included a few key details, like: How you got to this point (what did you do?), your PostgreSQL version, how you installed PostgreSQL and from where, your OS X version, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This could be two things: you lost/misset the password, or Postgres might be configured in a way that prevents you from logging in.

Resetting the password:

Most of the time Postgres runs as user "postgres". Try `su - postgres` as root, and then run `psql`. If that doesn't work, you'll need to figure out what user postgres is running as, and su to that user. From there you can reset the password for the user. Also, make sure that your user is allowed to log in -- the default is to disable login for a new role .

Changing the configuration:

Find the pg_hba.conf file and edit it to permit password login. This file is usually loacted in /var/lib somewhere. On my Scientific Linux server its at: `/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/pg_hba.conf`, but on my Gentoo server its at `/etc/postgresql-9.3/pg_hba.conf` -- so `locate pg_hba.conf` might help you find it. This file is usually fairly well commented, and there is a manual page for it here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html.

Comment: Re your advice re su'ing to the `postgres` user: This only works if `pg_hba.conf` is configured for `peer` mode authenticaiton on on unix sockets. That's the default on most installs, but should not be assumed if somebody's messed up. Also, you should be using `sudo -u postgres`.

Comment: I thought the "Postgres might be configured in a way that prevents you from logging in" was a reasonable catchall, but obviously I'm wrong. Feel free to edit my answer -- I hardly use osx.

Comment: It's saying invalid for user quantumpotato, not postgres. (Sorry I had <my user name> in the original post which didn't show)

Comment: I tried $ su postgres psql
Password:
/usr/local/bin/psql: /usr/local/bin/psql: cannot execute binary file.